# Postfix: Two domains in mydestination - where are the mails delivered to?

Tags: postfix, alias

I have two domains in the `mydestination` parameter of Postfix:

```
mydestination = foo.com, bar.net
```

The MX-Records for `foo.com` and `bar.net` are set to `mail.foo.com`. In my `/etc/aliases` I map `admin` to the user `john`

```
admin: john
```

When I send mails to `admin@foo.com` the mails are accepted and delivered to `/home/john/Maildir/`.
When I send mails to `admin@bar.net` the mails are accepted with `relay=mail.foo.com` but they don't arrive in John's inbox.

1. **Why?**
2. **Where the heck are the mails for `admin@bar.net`?**

Comment: please post the relevant log lines in maillog. Providing output of `postconf -n` will help others understand your problem

Comment: How did you solve the problem @horen? Still having problems?

Answer (score 1):

Use `virtual_alias_maps` for this case, e.g in main.cf:

```
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

And in `/etc/postfix/virtual` put the following:

```
admin@foo.com    john
admin@bar.com    john
```

You can there use full emailadresses, not only usernames. Without a domain, the hostname/mailname of your system/postfix will be used. This is an important feature when dealing with multiple domains.

`/etc/alias` is for local aliases only.

Don't forget to run `postmap` and `newaliases` respectively.